# How to redirect to two different pages based on overriding Edit button in Account Detail page

Tags: visualforce

I have two Person Account Edit pages(A and B, which are visual force pages) after saving page A, 
I get redirected to Person Account Detail page. 
when clicking on the Edit option in Person Account Detail page, 
I am redirected to Person Account Edit screen of Page B.
Currently I get redirected only to Page B. 
How can i get an option to redirect to both the Person Account Edit pages(A and B)?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are there two pages? What would dictate the use of one over the other? You'll probably have to either create a third page to allow the choice or make page B redirect to page A if there are criteria involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a 3rd Visualforce page and on that page redirect them to the correct page based on the logic of your choosing.

or you can merge both pages into one and use pageblock sections to differentiate the pages and pick the pageblock section that is supposed to be visible based on the init but that can be confusing quick.